# How can you set a Gradle property to different values in the configuration step?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

[This Android example build file](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) contains the snippet

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
```

But since Gradle always executes all configure statements in the build script, won't this always set minifyEnabled to true even for a debug build?

I *wish* Gradle would let me set a variable to true in one task and false in another and configure things differently, but the only way I've been able to do it is by waiting for taskGraph.whenReady. This is how it normally works:

```
def myBool = false

task runs {
    myBool = true
}

task doesNotRun {
    myBool = false
}

task whoWins(dependsOn: runs) {
    doLast { println "myBool is ${myBool}" }
}

gradle whoWins
:runs
:whoWins
myBool is false
```

Comment: Are you trying to set a "variable" that you are defining and using, or are you trying to set a task "property"?

Comment: Why do you need to have multiple tasks set the same value at configuration time (as opposed to run-time)?

Comment: Does it matter, `def myBool = false` versus `ext.myBool = false`? The example works the same.

It just seems weird that if you want to set `source = someFiles`, you do it at config time, but if you should want to set `source = debug ? someFiles : otherFiles`, you have to do it at runtime or possibly in `taskGraph.whenReady`.

Comment: Have you tried using [doFirst](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:doFirst%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)? Why do you want to set it during config time?

Comment: Because `task doOneWay` and `task doTheOtherWay` have to depend on `task theThingToDo` and not the other way around, so theThingToDo has to run first. That's why there is a config step, so theThingToDo can get information about tasks that run after it.

The Android example seems to be setting the variable at config time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration step is to help Gradle build the task execution graph (what will actually be run), which is why all the configuration code is executed. What you are describing sounds like a circular task dependency, where a task depends on a variable being set by a task that in turn depends on the first task.

```
Task A -> depends on Task B -> depends on variable from Task A
```

What you are probably looking for is the ability to configure a task based on the execution graph. See the Gradle user guide, section 6.13 [Configure by DAG](https://docs.gradle.org/2.7/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#configure-by-dag). Using this allows you to break your circular dependency.

```
Task A -> depends on Task B -> depends on gradle.taskGraph.whenReady
```

or alternatively you can create a new task, Task C, that handles setting the variable based on the task graph.

```
def myBool = false

task runs {}

task doesNotRun {}

task whoWins(dependsOn: runs) {
    doLast { println "myBool is ${myBool}" }
}

task taskC << {
    if (gradle.taskGraph.hasTask(runs)) {
        myBool = true
    } else if (gradle.taskGraph.hasTask(doesNotRun)) {
        myBool = false
    }
}
runs.dependsOn(taskC)
doesNotRun.dependsOn(taskC)
```

Results:

```
$ gradle whois
:taskC
:runs
:whoWins
myBool is true
```

Comment: I never thought of checking the task graph at run time, that seems a lot cleaner than a bunch of code in taskGraph.whenReady.

I had read something like this in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sub:real_life_examples , but it didn't take I guess.

It seems like the only way for the Android code to work is not to check `if minifyEnabled` because that would always be true, but `if taskGraph.hasTask(release) {//then check if minifyEnabled}`.